# displaying contents of the list

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces, jstl

What's wrong with this jstl code please? I can't see its contents.

contents of my accueil.jsp page

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <th><c:out value="Numéro de compte"/></th>
           <th><c:out value="Date création"/></th>
           <th><c:out value="Date mise-à-jour"/></th>
           <th><c:out value="Libelle"/></th>
           <th><c:out value="Type devise"/></th>
           <th><c:out value="Situation compte"/></th>        
       </tr>

       <c:forEach items="${ sessionScope.listCpts }" var="liste">
           <tr>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="/menu"/>">${ liste.value.rib }</a></td>
                <td>${ liste.value.dateCréation }</td>
                <td>${ liste.value.dateMaj }</td>
                <td>${ liste.value.libelle }</td>
                <td>${ liste.value.typeDevise }</td>
                <td>${ liste.value.situationCompte }</td>
           </tr> 
       </c:forEach>
</table>
```

my doPost method

```
public static final String ATT_LIST_CPT       = "listCpts";
public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ConnexionForm form = new ConnexionForm();

        User user = form.connecterUser( request );

        ServiceService service = new ServiceService();
        tn.bh.services.client.Service srvc = service.getServicePort();
        List<Compte> listCpts = srvc.consulterListeCpt(user.getIdentifiant());

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        request.setAttribute( ATT_LIST_CPT, listCpts );
        request.setAttribute( ATT_FORM, form );
        request.setAttribute( ATT_USER, user );

        if ( form.getErreurs().isEmpty() ) {
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_USER, user );
            response.sendRedirect( request.getContextPath() + "/accueil" );
        } else {
            session.setAttribute( ATT_SESSION_USER, null );
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response );
        }

}
```

this is what looks like my html page generated. 
Note that my list (listCpts) is filled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing data in request scope and then you are invoking request.sendRedirect() so it will generate new request from client which will loose the data

either put the data to session scope

```
    session.setAttribute( ATT_LIST_CPT, listCpts );
```

or just forward request instead of redirection

and then change

```
${ sessionScope.listCpts }
```

to

```
${listCpts}
```

Comment: are you sure list is filled ? can you check the size of the list server side once ?

Comment: ${ listCpts.count } ?

Comment: I've put this line "System.out.println(listCpts.size());" and when I run it I've got 1 as result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access the object's attributes by using this

> ${ liste.dateCréation }

instead of

> ${liste.value.dateCréation}

and avoid using accented characters in the attributes' names.